# How do I convert a file object to a populated file input so I can submit via form?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a file object that I have gotten from drag and drop from desktop. I am trying to populate a hidden file input of which I can perform submission with it. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways. You don't necessarily need a hidden file input.

1. Use `xhr.send(file)`: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-send-blob
2. Use `xhr.send(formData)`: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-send-formdata
3. Actually use a hidden `<input type="file">`:

   ```
   <style>
   #files {
     position: absolute;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     opacity: 0.0;
     z-index: 2;
   }
   [type='submit']{
     display: none;
   }
   #drop {
     position: relative;
     margin: auto;
     width: 500px;
     height: 300px;
   }
   </style>

   <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
     <div id="drop"> 
       <div>Drop files here</div> 
       <input id="files" type="file" name="file" multiple> 
     </div> 
     <input type="submit"> 
   </form> 

   <script>
   document.querySelector("#files").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
     document.querySelector("[type='submit']").click();
   }, false);
   </script>
   ```

The key to the last one is the `opacity: 0;height: 100%;width: 100%` on the file input.

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

> (File API) Using the **`FileReader.readAsDataURL(file)`** call, every time a file is completely read, a new “data URL” (RFC 2397) formatted object is created and an event wrapping it is fired to the onloadend handler on the FileReader object.
>
> (FYI: The “data URL” object is Base64-encoded binary data, with a spec-defined header sequence of chars. Browsers understand them.)
>
> (File API) Now that we have the “data URL” object from the event, we can do cool things with it like replace the src attribute of an  tag to immediately show the value on-screen OR **upload the Base64-encoded portion of the data to a server to process as binary data**.

**[Source](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/)**

Comment: this doesn't answer how it can be converted into a populated file input.

Comment: @Nubela, I assumed that you only wanted to do that in order to upload the file? If not, then why?

Comment: because i'm trying to get django to see it, and even tho im having success using xhr to send the binary across, alot of stuff like csrf, etc are missing and making it extremely hard to process with django. hence with native form support, at least i can make that easier.